# eager execution on tensorflow2.3.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, eager-execution

I'm doing a beginner course on TensorFlow. The version I have installed is 2.3.0. I have had problems with eager execution since the course's TensorFlow version is different from the one I have installed. Does anyone know how I can perform an eager execution?

As an example,

```
    import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf 
        
        
    x = tf.constant([3,5,7])
    y = tf.constant([1,2,3])
    z1 = tf.add(x,y)
    z2 = x*y
    z3 = z2-z1
        
    print(z2)
       
    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as sess:
        a1, a2, a3 = sess.run([z1,z2,z3])
        print(a1)
        print(a2)
        print(a3)
```

where I get as the output for the eager execution
Tensor("mul_6:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)

Comment: Eager execution is on by default in tensorflow 2.x. If you provide a reproducible, minimal example, it will be much easier for stackoverflow users to helpful answers.

Comment: Hi jakub, thanks for your recommendation. I included the example and only the output for eager execution

Answer (score 3):

if you want to have eager execution - import tf the regular way, not `tensorflow.compat.v1`. Then there is no need to use `session` at all. just enter formulas and print results:

```
import tensorflow as tf

x = tf.constant([3,5,7])
y = tf.constant([1,2,3])
z1 = tf.add(x,y)
z2 = x*y
z3 = z2-z1

print(z1)
print(z2)
print(z3)

tf.Tensor([ 4  7 10], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([ 3 10 21], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
tf.Tensor([-1  3 11], shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Hi @Poe, the output that I get with your code, in my version of tensorflow2.3.0 is

Tensor("Add_9:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
Tensor("mul_9:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)
Tensor("sub_10:0", shape=(3,), dtype=int32)

Comment: make sure that you import tf as `import tensorflow as tf` and not `import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf `. Otherwise you get no eager execution enabled.